# Remote access Via HTTPS instead of RDP?

Tags: rdp

I'd like to be able to create a Ubuntu VM which will allow access to the desktop via a web portal so i can access the machine from any web browser enabled machine.

The typical use would be to allow me to securely use my home internet in the situation where I am connecting a personal machine to a public network with highly restrictive web filtering. I am assuming its highly likely that basic RDP would be blocked and would prefer to use an HTTPs/java based solution or similar.

I think the chrome RDP plugin works fairly well but is not really suited as an always on solution.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: What about [noVNC](https://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/)?

Comment: A non-answer to your question, but have you considered using OpenVPN and configuring it to use TCP 443?  I ran one that way for awhile for public wifi's that only allowed 80/443.  Obviously this doesn't work for 'any web browser enabled machine' but for your personal machine it's pretty slick.

Comment: That actually sounds like a very good suggestion for what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The thread is old and I know that.
But it is often a question and my solution is [Apache Guacamole™](https://guacamole.apache.org/).
Even firewalls with application control don't block this access AFAIK.